# Reduce image dimension with mapping

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a .png image with four colors in it. If I convert the image to a numpy array I get an array with the following dimensions: `[length X height X 3]`, with `length == height`.
How can I reduce the dimension with mapping the colors?

This is the current structure:

```
array([[[  0,  65, 101],
    [  0,  65, 101],
    [  0,  65, 101],
    ...,
    [  0,  65, 101],
    [  0,  65, 101],
    [  0,  65, 101]],

   [[  0,  65, 101],
    [163, 219, 232],
    [163, 219, 232],
    ...,
    [  0,  65, 101],
    [163, 219, 232],
    [  0,  65, 101]],

   [[  0,  65, 101],
    [163, 219, 232],
    [  0,  65, 101],
    ...,
    [  0,  65, 101],
    [163, 219, 232],
    [  0,  65, 101]],

   ...,

   [[  0,  65, 101],
    [163, 219, 232],
    [  0,  65, 101],
    ...,
    [  0,  65, 101],
    [  0,  65, 101],
    [  0,  65, 101]],

   [[  0,  65, 101],
    [163, 219, 232],
    [163, 219, 232],
    ...,
    [163, 219, 232],
    [163, 219, 232],
    [  0,  65, 101]],

   [[  0,  65, 101],
    [  0,  65, 101],
    [  0,  65, 101],
    ...,
    [  0,  65, 101],
    [  0,  65, 101],
    [  0,  65, 101]]], dtype=uint8)
```

And I would like an array with two dimensions, and every value in the `i'th` row and `j'th` column would correspond to the color it had in the third dimension. So if the original image had `7 X 7 X 3` dimension with four colors, the output would be something like this:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 0],
   [0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
   [0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
   [0, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

The values in the forementioned arrays are all made up, so they don't correspond to each other, I have just tried to represent the concept.

I read the picture as:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('image.png')
imgarray = np.asarray(img)

print(imgarray)
```

Comment: When you say you want the colour in the 3rd dimension what do you mean by that? the colour is the combination of the R, G and B values. Do you want the average or something else?

Comment: A mapping from the RGB colors in the third dimenson to the 0,1,2,3 set. Lets say I have black, green, cyan and purple. I want the black to be 0, the greens to be 1, cyans to be 2 and the purples to be 3 as the values in the two dimensional representation.

Comment: I guess then you just want the maximum value then? or is there a different way of choosing when you have values in multiple colours for the same pixel?

Comment: The RGB dimension gives us the colour of that pixel, but I don't want to store the picture in this three-dimensional array, rather in a two dimensional with the colours represented as simple values in each element of the array since they are only taking values from a small set.

Comment: Take a look at the function [`_palettize(a)`](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/numpngw/blob/master/numpngw.py#L456) that I wrote as part of the `numpngw` module.

Comment: @Newl my question is, if I have a pixel of [120, 30, 0, 200] for BGCP, which colour do you want to map to in your new array

Comment: @SvenHarris imgarray[i][j] can give me 4 type of colour arrays: black or green or cyan or purple ( [128,0,128] for purple, [0,255,0] for green etc.) I would like to map these arrays into a single value so when I index it with imgarray[i][j], it would give me just the number '3' (if the colour in the third dimension is purple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.unique` for this.  For example, here's a 3x5 image that has just three colors:

```
In [105]: img
Out[105]: 
array([[[10, 20, 30],
        [ 5,  5,  0],
        [ 5,  5,  0],
        [ 5,  5,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0]],

       [[ 5,  5,  0],
        [ 5,  5,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0]],

       [[10, 20, 30],
        [10, 20, 30],
        [10, 20, 30],
        [10, 20, 30],
        [ 5,  5,  0]]])
```

Call `numpy.unique` on the reshaped image.  The first two dimensions are flattened into a single dimension, and then `axis=0` is used so we get the unique colors.  `inv` will holds the array of "inverses", i.e. the indices into `colors` of the original values.

```
In [106]: colors, inv = np.unique(img.reshape(-1, 3), axis=0, return_inverse=True)

In [107]: colors
Out[107]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 5,  5,  0],
       [10, 20, 30]])

In [108]: inv
Out[108]: array([2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1])
```

Reshape `inv` to get the array of indices into `colors` with the same shape as the original image:

```
In [109]: inv.reshape(img.shape[:2])
Out[109]: 
array([[2, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 1]])
```